# Get small thumbnails from bigger photos

Tags: php, angularjs, thumbnails

I have a galery of users that show all of user photos. I want to have small thumbnails for each photos.

How to make it? 
Also I notice some website even create thumbnail that focus on the face part of the original photos.
I don't have any code just looking for suggestions. 
Im using PHP, Codeigniter, Angularjs, Jquery.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller when receiving the file, before uploading it, you need to do some processing to it. each image you will save it in 4 or 3 sizes, it will be like this for image called `imageHello.jpg`:`

```
site.com/images/large/imageHello.jpg
site.com/images/small/imageHello.jpg
site.com/images/thump/imageHello.jpg
```

So basically it will be `site.com/images/[size]/imageHello.jpg`, in the front end side you will file the `size` with what you want based on the page.

for zooming you can use this [library](https://github.com/igorlino/angular-elevatezoom-plus), look at this [example](http://igorlino.github.io/angular-elevatezoom-plus/#/main)

Comment: Good to know. But Im looking for a solution when crop the images. The code know where the face is and crop that area.

Comment: what? you need the code to know by itself where the face and the hand is ?

Comment: You must be shock haha but somebody did that. Check out the vietnamcupid.com. The thumbnail crop exactly where the faces are.

Comment: that wasn't your question :/